# Java DateTimeFormatterBuilder with Verbose Time Zone

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, java-time, datetime-parsing

Suppose I have a date such as:

> Nov 30, 2013 19:00:00.001930000 Eastern Standard Time

I'm trying to parse the input using [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), but I can't figure out what to put for the `Set` of generic type [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) which is `null` below.

```
String basePattern = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss";
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern(basePattern)
        .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND,0,9, true)
        .appendZoneText(TextStyle.FULL, null)
        .toFormatter();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pseudo zones

As the [class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendZoneText-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Set-) explains briefly, the 3-4 letters commonly seen in mainstream media to indicate a time zone are not actually official time zones. These pseudo-zones are not standardized, and are not even unique! Many codes are re-used around the globe. For example, `IST` is both India Standard Time and Irish Standard Time. And `CST` is both China Standard Time and [Central Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone) (in North America).

Never use these pseudo-zones. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`.

### Resolving ambiguity

If your input does have these pseudo zones, in the abbreviated format, you have to deal with the ambiguity. By default, the formatter builder will attempt to resolve the ambiguity by considering the `Locale` of formatter. In the case of `CST` if the [`Locale`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java9locales-3559485.html) is `Locale.CHINA`, then perhaps the `CST` means China Standard Time rather than Central Standard Time.

Unfortunately this is a crude approach. The issues of **`Locale` and time zone are orthogonal**. You could have an Chinese-speaking user handling data for deliveries in Chicago in which case the [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) may be China but the `CST` found in the data means [Central Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone). So in such cases, you can specify one or more time zones such as [`America/Chicago`](https://time.is/Chicago) and [`America/Winnipeg`](https://time.is/Winnipeg) to be considered by the formatter when trying to parse `CST` to override the default of considering the `Locale`.

```
Set< ZoneID > zones = new TreeSet<>() ;
zones.add( ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ;
zones.add( ZoneId.of( "America/Manitoba" ) ;
…
.appendZoneText( TextStyle.SHORT , zones ) 
…
```

Here is a full example, parsing `CST` as Central Standard Time on my macOS MacBook set to default time zone of `America/Los_Angeles` and default locale of `Locale.US`. Notice that we pass only a single argument to `appendZoneText` (no `Set` passed).

```
String input = "Nov 30, 2013 19:00:00.001930000 CST";  
String basePattern = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder( )
        .appendPattern( basePattern )
        .appendFraction( ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND , 0 , 9 , true )
        .appendPattern( " " )
        .appendZoneText( TextStyle.SHORT  )
        .toFormatter( );

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );

System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt );
```

> input: Nov 30, 2013 19:00:00.001930000 CST
>
> zdt.toString(): 2013-11-30T19:00:00.001930-06:00[America/Chicago]

Let's pass the `Set` of `ZoneId` objects to override that behavior, hinting that `CST` means `China Standard Time`. Here we *do* pass a `Set` of `ZoneId` objects. We use the same input to get a very different output.

```
Set < ZoneId > zones = new HashSet <>( );
zones.add( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Shanghai" ) ) ;

String input = "Nov 30, 2013 19:00:00.001930000 CST";  
String basePattern = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder( )
        .appendPattern( basePattern )
        .appendFraction( ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND , 0 , 9 , true )
        .appendPattern( " " )
        .appendZoneText( TextStyle.SHORT , zones )
        .toFormatter( );

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );

System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt );
```

> input: Nov 30, 2013 19:00:00.001930000 CST
>
> zdt.toString(): 2013-11-30T19:00:00.001930+08:00[Asia/Shanghai]

Now, in your case, you have the full name of the pseudo-zone rather than the abbreviation. So there is likely no ambiguity. So you probably could get away with the [overloaded method not taking a second argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendZoneText-java.time.format.TextStyle-).

```
.appendZoneText( TextStyle.FULL )
```

Example:

```
String input = "Nov 30, 2013 19:00:00.001930000 Eastern Standard Time";  
String basePattern = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder( )
        .appendPattern( basePattern )
        .appendFraction( ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND , 0 , 9 , true )
        .appendPattern( " " )
        .appendZoneText( TextStyle.FULL )
        .toFormatter( );

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );

System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt );
```

> input: Nov 30, 2013 19:00:00.001930000 Eastern Standard Time
>
> zdt.toString(): 2013-11-30T19:00:00.001930-05:00[America/New_York]

Yet there *is* a usefulness to passing a `Set` of `ZoneId` objects here too. The `Set` is used in assigning the time zone to the instantiated `ZonedDateTime` object. Notice in output above that `America/New_York` was assigned by default. But there are many other time zones that are also implied by the pseudo-zone “Eastern Standard Time”, such as the Bahamas, `America/Nassau`, and Cancun in Mexico, and so on.

Which element in the set is chosen to be applied is a mystery to me however. I tried to use a `SortedSet` thinking the first found in the natural order of the Set may be chosen. Alas, `ZoneId` does not implement `Comparable` interface so a `SortedSet` such as `TreeSet` cannot be used.

```
Set < ZoneId > zones = new HashSet <>( );
zones.add( ZoneId.of( "America/Detroit" ) );
zones.add( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) );
zones.add( ZoneId.of( "America/Nassau" ) );
zones.add( ZoneId.of( "America/Cancun" ) );

String input = "Nov 30, 2013 19:00:00.001930000 Eastern Standard Time";  
String basePattern = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder( )
        .appendPattern( basePattern )
        .appendFraction( ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND , 0 , 9 , true )
        .appendPattern( " " )
        .appendZoneText( TextStyle.FULL , zones )
        .toFormatter( );

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );

System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt );
```

> input: Nov 30, 2013 19:00:00.001930000 Eastern Standard Time
>
> zdt.toString(): 2013-11-30T19:00:00.001930-06:00[America/Cancun]

Comment: Just one detail: it's better to specify the locale (such as `toFormatter(Locale.US)`) because those zone names are locale-sensitive. In my JVM the default is `pt_BR` (Brazilian Portuguese) and the parsing fails (it works only if the zone name is `Horário de luz natural oriental`). The locale is also required due to month name (in pt_BR, they're all lowercase and it also fails for this case - I had to change the input to `nov`). And in my JVM, the last example is resolved to `America/Nassau`. Maybe it just gets the first element returned by the set (which has no guaranteed order), who knows...